# General Monthly Totals in a column oriented matrix

Tags: powerbi

I have a PBI matrix that looks as follows:

[image]

What I would like to do is to have PBI show yearly totals at the end of each year as additional columns in the matrix. So, there would be a yearly total after the "2017-12" column and one after "2018-07". Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you create a date hierarchy and having years as columns, and then drill down to months, etc.?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov - Because that isn't how the client wants to see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey suggested, you can create a hierarchy with year above month so that Power BI will subtotal at that level. It should look something like this when you drill down to the month level:

[image: Hierarchy example]

If this isn't satisfactory, then you'll have to do things much more manually.